# Tem como inicializar apenas alguns membros de um array em C já na sua definição?

Tags: c, array, c++, sintaxe, declaração-de-variável

Eu sei que pode fazer isto:

```
int a[5] = { 0, 3, 8, 0, 5 };
```

ou

```
int a[5];
a[1] = 3;
a[2] = 8;
a[4] = 5;
```

Tem como fazer o mesmo em apenas uma linha, já na definição? Ou seja, dá para inicializar só alguns elementos?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tem uma sintaxe para isto:

```
int a[5] = { [1] = 3, [2] = 8, [4] = 5 };
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/SelectiveInitialization.c).

Pode até ser em qualquer ordem. Esta sintaxe é a mesma que fazer a atribuição depois da declaração.